# Why first table should be in left and second on right in left/right join in sql server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have to use Left outer join, i am confused to find the logic why I choose 1 table in left and another in right, is there a reason behind it?

For eg. I can guess left table should be one which having NULL value in joining column

Comment: You get all the rows from the "left side" table, and only matching rows from the "right side" table in a "left join". That's the exact meaning, so basically, which table do you want all the rows from?

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen- My question is not about the functionality of Left/Right join. My doubt is, I can achieve what I want from Left join and same result from Right join by swapping the table name, then when to use Right/Left

Answer (score 0):

Refer this,

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/difference-between-a-left-outer-join-and-right-outer-join/

The difference is simple – in a left outer join, all of the rows from the “left” table will be displayed, regardless of whether there are any matching columns in the “right” table. In a right outer join, all of the rows from the “right” table will be displayed, regardless of whether there are any matching columns in the “left” table. Please refer the examples in the shared URL.

Please google it you can find what you need.

Comment: My question is not about the functionality of Left/Right join. My doubt is, I can achieve what I want from Left join and same result from Right join by swapping the table name, then when to use Right/Left

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Evaluation (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), EvalName varchar(30), EvalDate datetime)
CREATE TABLE #EvaluationDetails (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), EvalID int, Points decimal(22,6), Question varchar(100) )


declare @Date datetime
set @Date = GETDATE()
INSERT INTO #Evaluation VALUES ('Specific question',@Date)

INSERT INTO #EvaluationDetails VALUES (1,10,'First question first evaluation')
INSERT INTO #EvaluationDetails VALUES (1,5,'SEcond question first evaluation')
INSERT INTO #EvaluationDetails VALUES (1,0,'Third question first evaluation')

INSERT INTO #EvaluationDetails VALUES (null,0,'First question therd evaluation')


SELECT * FROM #Evaluation  e
join #EvaluationDetails ed on ed.EvalID = e.ID

SELECT * FROM #Evaluation e
left join #EvaluationDetails ed on ed.EvalID = e.ID

SELECT * FROM #Evaluation e
right join #EvaluationDetails ed on ed.EvalID = e.ID



DROP TABLE #Evaluation
DROP TABLE #EvaluationDetails
```

So let's take the following example. The result of the queries ( join/left/right)

[image]

So as you can see we have 2 evaluation which have their details in an other table. It's a metter of what you want to get. IF you are interested in getting all the evaluation that have details ( questions ). You do a simple join. If you want to get all the evaluation even those that don't have an answer you do a left join between `#Evaluation` and `#EvaluationDetails`. If you want to get all the questions even the ones that don't have an evaluation, you do a right join.

This is the way joins work. Of course if you switch the tables and join `#EvaluationDetails` with `#Evaluation` you switch the joins too, so the left join becomes right join and the right join becomes left join.

Comment: @ CiucaS - My question is not about the functionality of Left/Right join. My doubt is, I can achieve what I want from Left join and same result from Right join by swapping the table name, then when to use Right/Left

Comment: @BrijeshKumar i guess the only difference I find is using `SELECT * FROM` becouse columns will the displayed in the way the tables are added to the join. So swapping the joins and the tables will result into a different column display and it may affect the Order by clause ( Order by can be used with 1, 2, 3 as column number from select).